# JQuery UI droppable drop only to a specific area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am having an issue trying to drag an element to the placeholder which has another placeholder in it.

Let say I have:

```
page.find("ol.question-group-placeholder").droppable({
    accept: ".question-type, .question-text",
    activeClass: "placeholder-active",
    hoverClass: "placeholder-hover",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        alert("Dropped to the question group!");
    }
});
```

and:

```
page.find("ol.question-placeholder").droppable({
    accept: ".question-text",
    activeClass: "placeholder-active",
    hoverClass: "placeholder-hover",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        alert("Dropped to the question!")
    }
});
```

The first one is question group OL which accepts only LI's with classes: `.question-type` and `.question-text`.

The second one is question OL which accepts only LI's with the class: `question-text`.

When I am dragging an element with the class `question-type` in the question group placeholder this becomes the place holder for the question text, but question group placeholder also accepts question text elements where the problem appears.

Problem is that when there are two place holders: `question-group-placeholder` and `question-placeholder` when I am dragging the text element both events are invoked and I see two alerts which makes sense because they both accepts `question-text` elements. What I am trying to achieve is if I am dragging question text to a specific placeholder it will only end up on this place holder, not on all of them. Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: What about "scope"-Parameter?

Comment: If I am using scope it will only apply elements to a specific area, I also need to able to drag text into question group and question, but when I am dragging it to question so that it won't appear in the question group and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

I needed to set greedy option to true (`greedy: true`) on both of them.